# Use a pointer to a char array to get the length of the string to copy using strstr()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I want to copy a part of a phrase to a char array, and then a second part of the same phrase to another one. I'm trying to use `strstr` and then `strcpy`, but I'm not sure I'm using the pointer in the right way. Here is my code.

```
void searchPer(char frase[], char frase_c[]) {
    char * p_per;
    char part1[MAX],part2[MAX];

    p_per = strstr(frase,"per");

    if (p_per == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    strncpy(part1,frase, *p_per);
    strncpy(part2,&frase[*p_per], frase-p_per);

    printf("%s", part1);
    printf("%s", part2);
}
```

The problem is I can't use the pointer given by `strstr` to access the right index of the phrase, I think. Right now the program is not printing anything to terminal.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ).  Start by removing the unused parameter: `frase_c`.

Comment: please read/understand the man page for `strstr()` and `strncpy().  amongst other things, strstr() returns a char pointer not an index.  and `strncpy()`, third parameter is a `size_t`, not a char pointer.

Comment: are you sure the `frase` points to a NUL terminated string?  If the string is not NUL terminated, then the strstr() will continue to access memory until is encounters a NUL byte.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: if `p_per` is NULL, then nothing will be printed.  regarding these kinds of lines: `printf("%s", part1);`  the format string needs to end with '\n'  so the line should be: `printf("%s\n", part1);`  so it will be immediately output to the terminal screen rather than sitting in the stdout buffer of the OS.   Suggest inserting a `printf()` statement before the `return` statement to let the user know the "per" string was not found

Answer (score 2):

The variable `p_per` is a pointer to a character. Dereferencing the pointer gives you the value stored in the memory the pointer points to, in your case a single character. The third argument to the [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) function is the *number of characters* to copy, which is not a single character.

For example, lets say that `*p_per` is the character `'A'`, in [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) that is `65` which means that you will copy 65 characters.

You need to use *pointer arithmetic* to calculate the number of bytes to copy, but using `p_per - frase`.

You should also make sure that the number of characters you copy is not more than `MAX - 1` (-1 to fit the terminator).

Answer (score 1):

strstr doesn't returns an index of the found character, but the adress itself.

You can do like that:

```
strncpy(part1, frase, p_per - frase);
part1[p_per - frase] = '\0';
strncpy(part2, p_per, MAX - 1);
```

Also, don't forget to add `\n` to your printfs.

Comment: now it is giving me a segmentation error while calling the first `strncpy` function. I read it is a index and pointer error, but i can't understand what's wrong here..

Comment: the strncpy() function adds the '\0' so you do not have to do it explicitly in the code.  and this line: `strncpy(part1, frase, p_per - frase);` should really be: `strncpy(part1, frase, (p_per - frase) >= MAX)? MAX-1 : p_per-frase);`

Comment: you might want to insert, before the first call to strncpy(): `printf( "length of part1: %ld\n", p_per-frase );`  to assure a valid value is being passed to the call to strncpy()

Comment: @user3629249 I removed the '\0' and it worked, thank you! i don't know why my book suggested me to manually add it after strncpy!